# The mPDF does not display images with spaces in the path

Tags: image, spaces, mpdf

I am using MODX.
For example, image with path `assets/modules/ZipUpload/Jemchug/mini_820094.jpg` displays correctly, but `assets/modules/ZipUpload/Duplicate of Kulonyi, Podvesyi/mini_820022.jpg` does not.

Answer (score 0):

In the `AdjustHTML` function of the `mpdf.php` file there is a line that causes this problem with images:

```php
$html = preg_replace("/[ ]+/",' ',$html);
```